# Coverage.py report split between a lot of HTML files

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

```
I am using coverage.py library for generating the code coverage report. But the issue is my coverage report is being split into different html files and they are not included in the **index.html** files
```

I tried of some ways to merge these reports but apparently I suppose there aren't any.

We see there are of lot of html files containing coverage reports of different files
[image]

but the index.html file is not containing these files.
[image]

Comment: Can you show your configuration settings? Do you have `[html] skip_covered=true` or `[html] skip_empty=true`?

Comment: If this problem persists, you can write an [issue for coverage.py](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/), including details of how to reproduce it.